# How to get the count of rows in a column between a range in a sql table

Tags: sql, count, range

In my table I have a column (Wt%) which has the following values 5, 6, 7, 9, 1, 3, 4.  I would like a script which will go through and get the count of the values in this column which fall between the range 5 and 9 inclusive.

eg. 4.

Thanks

Comment: This is a fairly simple question that can easily be found by searching please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for standard question asking proceedures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select COUNT(*)
FROM yourTable
WHERE columnName >=5 and columnName <=9
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM MyTable
WHERE Wt% <= 9 AND Wt% >= 5
```

Answer (score 1):

select count(*) FROM Table WHERE Wt% >= 5 AND Wt% <= 9

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE Wt >= 5 AND Wt <= 9`